# What is a "platform token" in SNS and/or APNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I get from Amazon SNS that my platform token is invalid. What is a platform token? Apple has a "device token", SNS has "endpoints" with tokens, along with "Applications" and "Application endpoints", but nowhere the word platform or "platform token".

Platform would indicate a broader error, but "platform token" would seem to refer directly to the token given by the device and connected to an endpoint.

I'm not asking how to fix, just what these words mean and where I might find them used elsewhere (if they are used elsewhere) ie. in Amazon docs.

> {"DeliveryAttempts":1,"EndpointArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:66511747:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/aaaaaaa/a4772ef2-b986-2e63-9642-644802a9f931","EventType":"DeliveryFailure","FailureMessage":"Platform
>   token associated with the endpoint is not
>   valid","FailureType":"InvalidPlatformToken","MessageId":"9046f641-91fe-5fc4-81e5-b94bd547b7ca","Resource":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:66511747:app/APNS_SANDBOX/aaaaaaa","Service":"SNS","Time":"2016-01-08T23:12:57.692Z"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record, it is the "device token".

In my particular case, Apple was giving me a production token on a development build, possibly because I had previously installed a production version of the app, but there are many possible reasons.

Comment: How did you confirm which type of token it was? Any way to get around this?

Comment: @DomHede - By taking the token and marking it as a production token in the database, seeing as the requests were accepted. Or something along those lines. That also caused it to work in the future, as the SNS service used allowed easy switching.

Comment: @user1122069 What do you mean marking it as a production token? My development/testflight build works but my production app doesnt, same error `Platform token associated with the endpoint is not valid`.